# How can I change IIS 7 server-wide SMTP settings for .NET 4

Tags: iis-7, web-config, smtp

I'm trying to configure the IIS 7 SMTP settings for .NET 4 web applications, so all sites use the same host. I've configured the host for the server inside the IIS manager, but this is only picked up by .NET 2 web apps.

.NET 4.0 applications don't pickup the host.

Is there a way to specify a machine-wide SMTP setting for .NET 4? The server is x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer: you need to add the `<system.net>` section to your machine.config file, for the framework, e.g.

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="blah@blah">
                <network host="123.321.123.321" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

IIS7 stores its SMTP settings in the metabase.xml file still, however you can configure it for a framework via the machine.config as that takes precedence.

You just need to remember that if you're on 64 bit server, the path is

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64